# Checking for suspension while retrieving user info in one query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, an account table and a suspension table. Rather than first retrieving their information upon login, and then another query to check for an active suspension, would it be possible to join two queries and check for both in one?

This query currently returns no rows if the user has no active suspension, which I don't want it to do. I'm hoping for it to return an empty result for the `suspension` table fields, and then all of their info.

```
SELECT `account`.`username`, `suspension`.`user_id` FROM `account`,`suspension` WHERE `account`.`user_id` = 5 OR `suspension`.`user_id` = 5
```

That would return 0 results. Without the `suspension` part, it would return the username of the user. I'm wanting it to return the username, and either an empty `suspension.user_id` or `0` for the field, if that's possible:

`username => Test,
 user_id  => 0`

```
CREATE TABLE `account` (
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `password` char(32) NOT NULL,
  `email_address` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `creation_date` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `creation_ip` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `suspension` (
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `suspension_reason` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `suspension_date` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `suspension_expire` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: You are looking for [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html). It allows you to join two tables together and get row data from each one. If you provide a layout of both of the tables I can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [Mysql Join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) to join the two tables together which reference the user id.

Account Table

```
CREATE TABLE `account` (
   `id` INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `username` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
);
```

Suspension Table

```
CREATE TABLE `suspension` (
   `user_id` INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES account(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Query

```
SELECT A.username, A.id FROM `account` AS A 
LEFT JOIN `suspension` AS S ON S.user_id = A.id
WHERE A.id = 5 AND S.user_id IS NULL;
```

If the user appears in Suspension, no results are returned. If the user isn't suspended then the user result is returned. To return the user and their suspension status, you can use the below query.

```
SELECT A.username, A.id, (S.user_id IS NOT NULL) AS `suspended` FROM `account` AS A 
LEFT JOIN `suspension` AS S ON S.user_id = A.id
WHERE A.id = 5;
```